# Can you connect Amazon ElastiСache Redis to amazon EMR pyspark?

Tags: amazon-emr, amazon-elasticache

I have been trying several solutions with custom jars from redislab and also with --packages in spark submit emr and still no suceess is there any simple way in emr to connect to elasticache ?